# number of images to be stored in the database

Tags: codeigniter-3

In my field download image, we can put a maximum of 3 images. and if the user selects 2 images we store the number of images in the database. but there it always puts the number of the image storage as 1 even if we just downloaded 3 images.

Views:

```
<div class="form-group">
                      <label for="nbr_image">Parcourir fichier :</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <div class="custom-file">
                          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="nbr_image"  accept=".gif,.png,.jpeg,.jpg" multiple onchange="checkFiles(this)">
                          <label class="custom-file-label" for="nbr_image">Choisir un maximum de 3 images</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Controller :

```
 public function insertProgramm() {
        $this->checkSession();
        // Définition des règles de validation pour le champ "type"
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('titre', 'Titre', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('region', 'Region', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('departement', 'Departement', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('ville', 'Ville', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', 'required|callback_validate_description');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('type', 'Type', 'required|in_list[neufs,nouveaux]');
        
        // $this->form_validation->set_rules('image', 'Image', 'callback_validate_image');
    
        // Validation des données du formulaire
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            // Si les données ne passent pas la validation, on affiche le formulaire à nouveau avec les erreurs
            $this->load->view('dashboard/AjoutProgrammView');
        } else {
            // Si les données sont valides, on continue le traitement
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array(
                'titre' => $this->input->post('titre'),
                'region' => $this->input->post('region'),
                'departement' => $this->input->post('departement'),
                'ville' => $this->input->post('ville'),
                'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
                'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
                'nbr_image' => count($upload_data['full_path']) // stocker le nombre d'images téléchargées
            );
    
            // insérer les données dans la base de données
            $this->DashboardModel->insertProgramm($data);
    
            // rediriger l'utilisateur vers la page de confirmation 
            redirect('dashboard/ListeProgramm');
        }
    }
```

Model :

```
public function insertProgramm($data) {
    // insérer les données dans la base de données
    $this->db->insert('programme', $data);
   
    // retourner le nombre de lignes affectées
    return $this->db->affected_rows();
}
```

I have already tried to use full_path but it always puts the number of image storage in 1.
`'nbr_image' => count($upload_data['full_path'])`

I hope you can help me to solve my problem